# How can I save the text-scale info when `desktop-save-in-desktop-dir`?

Tags: desktop, zooming

By default, even if I `text-scale-decrease` in some frames before I `desktop-save-in-desktop-dir`, when I restart Emacs and `desktop-read`, all frames show in the default text-scale.

How can I save the text-scale info for each frame every time I evoke `desktop-save-in-desktop-dir command`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Variable `text-scale-mode-amount` is what you want to save.  But it is *buffer-local*.  I don't think Desktop restores buffer-local variables, but if it does then it should already be working for you, I would think.

You can of course set the *default* text-scale value, i.e., for all buffers, to some value in your init file, if you want:

```
(setq-default text-scale-mode-amount  1) ; Or 2 or whatever.
```

But that's not the same thing as saving, for *each buffer*, its *last* value.

---

Another approach, since you mentioned frames, is to zoom the *frames*, not buffers.

You can zoom either frames or buffers using the commands in library [`zoom-frm.el`](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/download/zoom-frm.el).  You can in fact use the same commands to zoom either a frame or a buffer.  You can use mouse buttons (e.g. with a modifier), keyboard keys, or the mouse wheel.

When you zoom a frame the `font` frame parameter changes to have a larger or smaller size.

Dunno whether Desktop saves all frame parameters.  I believe it saves some, at least.  If it saves the `font` parameter (and I think it does) then all of your zoomed frames should be restored at their last zoom levels in your next Emacs session.